# Is there a way to execute required php file once per session?

Tags: php

I am new to php and have just written a basic index.php that will display family tree information for an individual based on input id.

The index.php includes a file called "xml-people-list.php" which loads the information from the family tree and creates a sorted list of people.

My problem is that every time you click on a person to display their details, the included php is reloaded which causes the read from file and creation of sorted list to happen again.

Is there a way to only run this code once per session to avoid multiple loads?

I tried to look at session variables but wasn't sure if they would help or how to use them in this case or if there is another way?

Contents of "xml-people-list.php:

```
<?php require 'xml-load-person.php';

    if (file_exists('people.xml'))
    {
        $people = simplexml_load_file('people.xml');

        foreach ($people->person as $person)
        {
            $person_list[(string)$person['ID']] = strtoupper($person->FamilyName) . ", " . $person->GivenNames;
        }

        asort($person_list);
    }
    else
    {
        exit('Failed to open people.xml.');
    }

?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use session variables. If you wanted to only parse the list once per visitor, and then "cache" the result into a session variable, you could do something like this (for a simple example):

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['person_list'])) {
    // Here we fetch and decode the the ready list from a session variable, if it's defined: 
    $person_list = json_decode($_SESSION['person_list']);
}
// Otherwise we load it:
else {
    require 'xml-load-person.php';

    if (file_exists('people.xml'))
    {
        $people = simplexml_load_file('people.xml');

        foreach ($people->person as $person)
        {
            $person_list[(string)$person['ID']] = strtoupper($person->FamilyName) . ", " . $person->GivenNames;
        }

        asort($person_list);

        // Here we assign the ready list to a session variable (as a JSON string):
        $person_list = json_encode($person_list);
        $_SESSION['person_list'] = $person_list;

        // Here we revert the JSON-encoded (originally SimpleXML) object into a stdClass object.
        $person_list = json_decode($person_list);
    }
    else
    {
        exit('Failed to open people.xml.');
    }
}
```

You will need to call [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) in your file (either this one, or any other file including it, but importantly before any output is sent to the browser). Homework: Read up on sessions in PHP.

**Update:** Since SimpleXML objects can't be serialized, and since adding an object to `$_SESSION` causes serialization, I've updated the answer to `json_encode/decode` the object. Yes there's a bit of processing, but that'd be the case with the default serialization as well, and json_en/decode is fairly light-weight. Certainly heaps lighter than parsing XML on each page load!

Be aware that the returned object will be a `stdClass` object, not a SimpleXML object. I'm assuming it won't be a problem in your use case.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to implement this, however, from what I have read you shouldn't store SimpleXML objects in session variables as they don't serialise. I receive the following error when I try "fatal error: uncaught exception: serialization of 'simplexmlelement' is not allowed in 0..."

Comment: Well that's a pain. However, while serialize fails, it's possible to json_encode a simplexml object -- resulting in a string you can then save into a session variable. Updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try require_once() function

Answer (score -1):

1) First of all, try to see if your buttons are anchor tags then be sure that the href attribute is directing to # example: `<a href="#">`

2) try to use `include_once` instead of requiring

3) if you tried this and these couple solutions didn't work for you you can send the id of a person using the global `$_GET` variable

//this should be you URL http://localhost/projectname/index.php?person_id=1
// your href of each person should appoint to their URL
// `<a href="index.php?person_id=1">`

you can use this `$_GET['person_id']` and store it into a variable so it will give you the id of person.

Comment: Appreciate the contribution, however did you understand OP's question?